# How can I filter on values of a columns which start with one of the three strings I indentify?

Tags: python, list, startswith

I have a column with different values of the type of product such as books, TV etc. How can I filter on the values of the column that starts either with books or movies?

I have tried but it is not filtering on the three values separately, I would have expected to only see in the categories column values which start with books or values that start with Movies.

```
#Create a list of values
filtering_list=['Books','Movies']
df=df[df.categories.str.startswith(filtering_list,na=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-startswith/

`str.startswith(str,na)` seems to take a string as first argument, not a list so you should filter for both books and movies and than concat the lists.

Something like blow should do the trick (not tested meant as pseudo code)

```
result = []
for filter in filtering_list:
  result.append(*df[df.categories.str.startswith(filter,na=False)])
```

(Note the asterisk to unpack the list.)